# code to find the largest number in the array but it only showing the first number as the largest. someone please let me know why

Tags: c++, arrays

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int findLargest()
{
    int arg[25],largest,size,i,j;
    cout<<"enter the size of array"<<endl;
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"enter the numbers"<<endl;
    for(i; i<size; i++)
    {
        cin>>arg[i];
    }
    for(j=1; j<size; j++)
    {
        largest=arg[0];
        if(arg[0]<arg[j])
        {
            largest==arg[j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"The largest number is : "<<largest;

}
int main()
{
findLargest();    

    return 0;}
```

whats wrong with this?
wrote this code to find the largest number in the array
but it only shows the first number in the array as the largest

Comment: your problem is the if statement, in it, you just compare the first number with all the others, always the first, so basically, if you change the if statement to check for the largest, then you should be fine....like this: if(largest<arg[j])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of mistakes in the code :

1. `i` is never initialized.
2. `largest=arg[0];` is put within the loop that makes `largest` always equal to `arg[0];`
3. In the statement `largest==arg[j];` it should be assignment not equality check i.e `largest = arg[j];`

Corrected code :

```
int findLargest()
{
    int arg[25],largest,size,i,j;
    cout<<"enter the size of array"<<endl;
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"enter the numbers"<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cin>>arg[i];
    }
    largest=arg[0];
    for(j=1; j<size; j++)
    {
        if(largest < arg[j])
        {
            largest = arg[j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"The largest number is : "<<largest;
    return largest; // in case caller function needs it.
}
```

Comment: that helped. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things,
`i` is uninitialized.

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    cin>>arg[i];
}
```

You set largest to the first element in every iteration, and then you compare every element to first element instead of `largest`. Then you use `==` instead of `=` to assign.
You also don't return anything from `findLargest()`, so you are better making it `void`.

```
largest = arg[0];
for(j=1; j<size; j++)
{
    if(largest<arg[j])
    {
        largest = arg[j];
    }
}
```

You might want to use `std::max_element()`

```
cout << *std::max_element(begin(arg), begin(arg)+size);
```

Comment: I would also add that he forgot the return statement in findLargest(), it needs to return an int

Comment: i is uninitialized? sorry i dont get it. declared int i and set it into 0, whats more?

Comment: @Harisvc In your code you forgot to set i to 0, but in Guarav's code he did to show you. If you don't do this then i could end up with a value you don't expect (123, 124151, -899, etc.)